# Multiple setTimeout functions but that goes off with different times

Tags: jquery

```
switch (e.keyCode) {

    case 32: 
        $("#Main").prepend('<div class="Bomb" style="absolute; top:' + position.top + 'px; left: '+ position.left +'px;"></div>');

        setTimeout( function(){ 

            var BombPos = $('.Bomb').position();

            var BombPosTopb = BombPos.top;
            var BombPosLeftb = BombPos.left;
            var BombPosTopt = BombPos.top;
            var BombPosLeftt = BombPos.left;
            var BombPosTopl = BombPos.top;
            var BombPosLeftl = BombPos.left;
            var BombPosTopr = BombPos.top;
            var BombPosLeftr = BombPos.left;
            $(this).remove();

            .... More stuff

            if (CheckRight == false){
                $("#Main").prepend('<div class="Effect" style="absolute; top:' + BombPosTopr + 'px; left: '+ BombPosLeftr +'px;"></div>');
                BombPosLeftr += 30;
            }
        };

        setTimeout( function(){ 
            $('.Effect').remove();
        }
        , 1000 );
    }
    , 1500 );
```

My project is called Bomberman and I am trying to spawn multiple Bombs.
The problem with this code: I spawn the object, it works & it goes awey without any problem.

But when I click multiple times my spacebar and put more than 1 bomb they all disappear **at the same time**.

I just want them to have a 'seperate timer' on each of my litle bombs so they go awey after 1-2 seconds when I click on the spacebar and not all at once.

Comment: When you have multiple bombs, do they all have the `.Bomb` css class? If so, isn't this a problem at `$('.Bomb').position()`?

Comment: They do have all .Bomb css, I tried to do it with $(".bomb").each() but that gave me an error also :/

Answer (score 0):

I think proper way would be to create a timeout method that will remove only the bomb whose time is up. F.e. by remembering the time you've started the timer for each bomb.

Answer (score 0):

Transform your bomb into objects.

You need a var that remember all your bomb placed :

```
var arrBombs = new Array();
```

then on `keypress`, add a new object:

```
case 32:
    arrBombs.push(new objBomb());
```

Then have a function for you objBomb that have your code :

```
function objBomb(){
    var self = this;
    self.el = $('<div/>');
    self.el.addClass('bomb')
    self.el.css({position : 'absolute', top : position.top + 'px', left : position.left+'px'})
    $("#Main").prepend(self.el);

    self.explosionTime = setTimeout( function(){ 

        self.BombPos = self.el.position();

        self.BombPosTopb = self.BombPos.top;
        self.BombPosLeftb = self.BombPos.left;
        self.BombPosTopt = self.BombPos.top;
        self.BombPosLeftt = self.BombPos.left;
        self.BombPosTopl = self.BombPos.top;
        self.BombPosLeftl = self.BombPos.left;
        self.BombPosTopr = self.BombPos.top;
        self.BombPosLeftr = self.BombPos.left;
        $(self).remove();

        .... More stuff

        if (CheckRight == false){
            $("#Main").prepend('<div class="Effect" style="absolute; top:' + BombPosTopr + 'px; left: '+ BombPosLeftr +'px;"></div>');
            BombPosLeftr += 30;
        }
    };
}
```

Code may not be exact, and you will surely have error. But for your project, creating obj is the best solution.

In case you don't know what objects are, check [MDN Working With Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Comment: Ty ver much, it is starting to work but my last problem with this object is now: before I did: $('.Bomb').remove() in my code but how do I say this in my object? I tried this.el.remove() or this.el.removeClass() but it doesnt work. Ty for help anyway

Comment: `this.el.remove()` should work, but if it's inside a function, it will not because you'll lose the reference of `this`. When you call a function, do : `this.fnName = function(arg){}` and you'll have access to `this`.

Comment: I do not understand your last sentence with this.fnName = function(arg){}, I just saw that my this.el.remove() stands in a function. Could you please give an example how to get the "this" but from the object itself and not the "this" from the function

Comment: Sorry, i just realised I miss guided you. You need to save the this value into a var who is into your object. I personnaly use self : `var self = this`. Then change all your "this" reference to self and all sould work! Click even example : http://jsfiddle.net/cLVd7/2/ and timer example: http://jsfiddle.net/cLVd7/3/

Comment: Oh and it will be self.el.remove

Comment: Maybe a litle more thing if possibel :$. For my litle Bom effect I use pictures so I had to make objects for them also, the only thing I am stuck at now is that self2.removeEffect is made in EffectBomb and isnt known in my objBomb function. Is it possibel to use a variable from another function?

Comment: In your obj Bomb, save your obj Effect `self.bombEffect = new objEffect`. To acces function in your obj from you bomb object, `self.bombEffect.yourFnName(arg)`. Check what i did here : http://jsfiddle.net/cLVd7/5/